# Oracle left join one to many

Tags: oracle

I have a two tables (for example a little minimized)

Table 1 : customer

```
Id  customerName
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
```

Table 2: order

```
Id  customerId  productName
1   2           ABC
2   2           DEF
3   4           ABC
4   5           FGH
```

I want to see all customers without an order. Something like:

```
customerId  
1   
3
```

So I tried

```
SELECT c.id as customerId
FROM customer_table c
LEFT JOIN order_table o
ON c.id = o.customerId
AND c.customerid IS NULL
```

But the result I get is:

```
customerId  
1
2
2
3
4
```

Please help to explain me what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine, and you only need to move the `NULL` check to a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT c.id as customerId
FROM customer_table c
LEFT JOIN order_table o
    ON c.id = o.customerId
WHERE o.customerid IS NULL;
```

[image]

### Demo

The problem with putting the `NULL` check in the `ON` clause is that it will cause every customer record to be retained in the result set, even if that record matches to no actual orders.  Note that your problem is sort of the opposite of what we typically see, which is putting logic in a `WHERE` clause which really belongs in an `ON` clause.

Demo in SQL Server, because to this day Oracle scares me.

Comment: yeah, sorry. I thought it was the same query accept for the o instead of c in the null check.

Answer (score 1):

`NOT EXISTS` is what you, probably, need:

```
SQL> with customer (id, name) as
  2    (select 1, 'a' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'b' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'c' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'd' from dual
  6    ),
  7  torder (id, customerid, productname) as
  8    (select 1, 2, 'abc' from dual union all
  9     select 2, 2, 'def' from dual union all
 10     select 3, 4, 'abc' from dual union all
 11     select 4, 5, 'fgh' from dual
 12    )
 13  select c.id
 14  from customer c
 15  where not exists (select null
 16                    from torder t
 17                    where t.customerid = c.id);

        ID
----------
         3
         1

SQL>
```

Or `MINUS` set operator (worse performance than `NOT EXISTS`):

```
select c.id from customer c
minus
select t.customerid from torder t;
```

Comment: Both queries are working. Love the minus. Only to bad it is worse for performance.

Comment: If your tables aren't large, MINUS will work just fine; you won't notice the difference.

Comment: one table has 1.600.000 records and the other one even more. So thats to bad.

Comment: Well, it won't cost much if you try it nonetheless.

Comment: I accepted the other question as answer because I was looking for a left join solution. But your solutions are also good. So +1

Answer (score 0):

```
  with tcustomer (id, name) as
      (select 1, 'a' from dual union all
       select 2, 'b' from dual union all
       select 3, 'c' from dual union all
       select 4, 'd' from dual
      ),
    torder (id, customerid, productname) as
      (select 1, 2, 'abc' from dual union all
       select 2, 2, 'def' from dual union all
      select 3, 4, 'abc' from dual union all
      select 4, 5, 'fgh' from dual
     )
   select c.id
   from tcustomer c
   where null not in (select null
                     from torder t
                     where t.customerid = c.id); 

Output:

ID
1
3
```